# DEV-C++ Notification: _CRTIMP int_ccdecl printf(const char*, ...)

Tags: c, notifications, dev-c++

I've started learning C and am using the *DEV-C++* Program.

Now always when i type in `printf("`

This appears:

```
_CRTIMP int_ccdecl printf(const char*, ...)
```

and it only goes away when I've completed the `printf` statement with the `;`

Can anyone tell me how to get can disable the Notification?

Since I can't post pictures jet, here is a Link to an uploaded version of the pic [elsewhere](http://postimg.org/image/h2xc2hw5v/). http://postimg.org/image/h2xc2hw5v/

I can't find it anywhere, and believe me, I've searched.

Comment: Please rephrase your question properly (including obvious spelling errors, it will make others take it more seriously and perhaps give you a proper answer).

Comment: Haven't you seen that popup with any other functions you have typed? Because it is probably telling you the signature of the function you are typing to help you know what the arguments are. (ok with `printf` it is not that usefull, but with other functions it is)

Comment: Trevor Hart, got the right answer, atleast for me.
And that hint also came for scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So....I'm going to assume that what you are saying is that it pops up an error when you are writing your code until you finish the full line, like intellisense...In Dev you should have an option at the top under tools->editor options-> and uncheck "Show Editor Hints".

Basically what is happening is it is trying to be helpful by telling you what is required to finish a function or whatever. Keep in mind if you do this it disables ALL help, there is no way to just get rid of one single thing like that.

As a side note, I wouldn't disable it. It is a very useful feature, basically it is telling you what arguments that function takes (A string of characters). It's really quite handy.